# HTML mark tags around mouse highlighted text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-frontend

I am trying to allow the user to select a section of text to perform commands on.

I have been trying to create `mark` tags around a section of a text that the user has highlighted with their mouse. If the user selects other text, the previously marked text should return to normal, and the new text should become marked.

I also want the user to only be able to select whole words at a time. Many of the methods I tried broke down because (I think) it couldn't deal with non-text tags such as `<br>` which made everything much more complicated when I tried using multiple mark tags instead of one.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

```js
const editordiv = document.getElementById("editordiv")

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelectionChange);

function handleSelectionChange(e) {
  if (e.target.activeElement !== editordiv) return;
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  // tried lots of things here but couldn't get any to work

}
```

```html
<div id="editordiv" contenteditable>Some multiline text here<br>lines</div>
```

Edit: Ok, I've spent way too long trying to solve this. Can someone please help?

Comment: What about `document.getElementById('editordiv').innerHTML.replaceAll(regex,'')`, where `regex` is something along the lines of `/<mark>|<\/mark>/gmi` (see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/8PMyWb/2))? You would use this as the first thing in your function. And later on you would use your current code for selection, etc.

Comment: But then I think the range indexes wouldn't work anymore since the contents of editordiv.innerHTML would have changed so the offsets wouldn't correspond to the correct indexes

Comment: Hi! Before attempting to code anything to help you, could you please describe the feature you want to achieve? What is the goal of using the `<mark>` element vs styling the selection using CSS?

Comment: I want users to be able to execute button triggered commands on the selected text so the selection needs to persist even when the div goes out of focus.

Comment: store the indexes before you replace the text. And since you always remove the same text, you can then add / subtract this to the past index.